# spacy doc.merge to using retokenizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

I want to convert the following code to using the new `spacy rekonizer.`. However I am not sure how exactly to go about doing it .

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
>>> doc = nlp("sydney is a cool town")
>>> t = doc.merge(0,6)
>>> t
sydney
>>> z = doc.merge(0,11)
>>> z
sydney is a
```

i tried the following but i get an error :

```
>>> with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
...      retokenizer.merge(0, 6)
...
```

i want to get the output in a variable like `t` or `z` above .

Comment: It will look like `with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    retokenizer.merge(doc[0:3])`, `print([token.text for token in doc])`.

Comment: @Wiktor how would I know 0:11 maps to 0:3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before retokenizing:

```
print([(idx,tok) for idx,tok in enumerate(samp)])
#this prints
#[(0, sydney), (1, is), (2, a), (3, cool), (4, town)]
```

You may try doing:

`retokenize.merge(doc[*index_of_token_to_start_from*:*index_of_ending_token* + 1])`

Full code to retokenize,

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(u"sydney is a cool town")
with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
    retokenizer.merge(doc[0:3])
print([(idx,tok) for idx,tok in enumerate(doc)]) #[(0, sydney is a), (1, cool), (2, town)]
```

Simlarily to merge *cool* *down* use, `doc[3:5]`